# How can I zoom at particular area of the UIImageView, where user double tap?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I found some result here, but can't figure out with my solution! and please, suggest me, some good example of zoom in/out on UIScrollView, I have done with it, but my UIImageView, is working normally!

Comment: We can't figure out what your problem is unless you share with us your code and explain what problem you are having and what you have tried to solve it. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before posting more questions

Comment: @NickBull thanks for suggestion! but my question is still in english language!

Comment: Yes, your question is in "English Language", but you also say it "is working normally". Therefore, where's the problem? But seriously, are you expecting us to do your work for you? Use Google to search for some "good example of zoom in/out on UIScrollView", or if you are having a specific problem, post what you have done so we can see you have at least put a little bit of effort into this and then explain your specific question. I'll point you once again to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: hey, @NickBull I am sorry, for my last comment!! I was little stucked in this problem so took your comment seriously! I hope u'll understand. thanks:) btw I solved my problem today!

Comment: @Hemang Shah: if you solved your problem than it would be a nice gesture to expand your question so others will know what the problem was; othervise this topic is just 'hanging out' here with no use to anyone. You can also accept your answer so we know this question had been answered allready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGPoint point=[sender locationInView:imageViewSelectedImage];
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(point.x-320, point.y-460) animated:YES];
```

You can increase / decrease your coordinates as requirements!

Comment: I used to zoom my imageView, in two taps action!